# Difference between operators "in" and or in Judgment statement

Tags: python

```
#workday progress and back step in weekend

dayfactor = 0.01
total_progress = 1
for i in range(365):
    if i % 7 == 6 or 0:
        total_progress *= 1-dayfactor
    else:
        total_progress *= 1+dayfactor
print("the total progress in a year is {:.2f}".format(total_progress))
```

The result of this code is `total_progress = 13.35`
but when I change `if i % 7 == 6 or 0` into `if i % 7 in [6,0]` which I suppose the code will show me the same result, but the `total_progress` changed to `4.63`. 
Is there any difference between this two codes?

Comment: `i % 7 == 6 or 0` is not correct; see [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: `i % 7 == 6 or 0` does not do what you think it does. It is equivalent to `0 or (i % 7 == 6)` and therefore also `i % 7 == 6`.

Comment: Although it sounds correct when you say it allowed, what you're really saying is 

    `if (i % 7 == 6) or (0)`

First you evaluate `i % 7 == 6` and if that is false, you check if `0` is true (which is always false). This means it's the same as just having:


    `if i % 7 == 6`

In the other example you explicitly check if the answer is a part of a list. It is more equivalent to `if (i % 7 == 6) or (i % 7 == 0)`

Comment: `if a == b or c:` is equivalent to `if (a == b) or c:`  In other words, `c` is treated as a Boolean value, and its value is OR-ed with the result of the comparison `a == b`.  Remember, Python is not an English language processor.